# W3C Feature (GeoLocation) Deprecation timelines

Tags: deprecated, w3c-geolocation

Now that W3C have officially deprecated the [GeoLocation API](https://w3c.github.io/geolocation-api/)

[image: *WARNING*]

How long do we have before our existing navigator.geolocation code stops working?

Is there some feature/API retirement that we can refer to as an example?

Most importantly who approved this? #GeoLocationIsNotaSensor! Sorry I take that back, *MOST* importantly who ask for a GeoLocation Sensor?

Comment: That warning links from Draft 11 to Draft 12 in a new location on w3c.github.io, where only the *path* changed, from `geolocation-api` to `geolocation-sensor`. Where are you reading that this has been *deprecated*?

Comment: If you are worried about the change in API when writing code using the old draft, first of all, this was a draft so is subject to change until final, and second, just test if the old `navigator.geolocation` attribute exists. If not, use the new sensor API to get a current position or use the promised-based read API to receive event callbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no mention of deprecation whatsoever in the page you linked to.

What this warning box says is that the specification of this API has been moved to an other working group, [Geolocation Sensor](https://w3c.github.io/geolocation-sensor/).

So given they even created an entire working group for this API, I'd bet it's not going to get away of browsers' implementations any time soon, <sub>but future can prove me wrong...</sub>

Comment: Yeah, I was a bit puzzled by this question. The Devices and Sensors Working Group is even a W3C Working Group! If anything the spec has been *promoted*, not deprecated, since the original document came from a W3C *Community* Group. (I'm a member of another W3C Community Group, so I'm somewhat familiar with how this works.)